# Any way to un-register a WPF dependency property?

Tags: .net, wpf, dependency-properties

I'm running into an unusual problem in my unit tests. The class I'm testing creates a dependency property dynamically at runtime and the type of that dependency property can vary depending on the circumstances. While writing my unit tests, I need to create the dependency property with different types and that leads to errors because you can't redefine an existing dependency property.

So is there any way to either un-register a dependency property or to change the type of an existing dependency property?

Thanks!

---

OverrideMetadata() only lets you change a very few things like default value so it isn't helpful. The AppDomain approach is a good idea and might work but seems more complicated than I really wanted to delve into for the sake of unit testing.

I never did find a way to unregister a dependency property so I punted and carefully reorganized my unit tests to avoid the issue. I'm getting a bit less test coverage, but since this problem would never occur in a real application and only during unit testing I can live with it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had similar issue just yesterday when trying to test my own DependencyProperty creating class. I came across this question, and noticed there was no real solution to unregister dependency properties. So I did some digging using [Red Gate .NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to see what I could come up with.

Looking at the `DependencyProperty.Register` overloads, they all seemed to point to `DependencyProperty.RegisterCommon`. That method has two portions:

First to check if the property is already registered

```
FromNameKey key = new FromNameKey(name, ownerType);
lock (Synchronized)
{
  if (PropertyFromName.Contains(key))
  {
    throw new ArgumentException(SR.Get("PropertyAlreadyRegistered", 
      new object[] { name, ownerType.Name }));
  }
}
```

Second, Registering the DependencyProperty

```
DependencyProperty dp = 
  new DependencyProperty(name, propertyType, ownerType, 
    defaultMetadata, validateValueCallback);

defaultMetadata.Seal(dp, null);
//...Yada yada...
lock (Synchronized)
{
  PropertyFromName[key] = dp;
}
```

Both pieces center around `DependencyProperty.PropertyFromName`, a HashTable. I also noticed the `DependencyProperty.RegisteredPropertyList`, an `ItemStructList<DependencyProperty>` but have not seen where it is used. However, for safety, I figured I'd try to remove from that as well if possible.

So I wound up with the following code that allowed me to "unregister" a dependency property.

```
private void RemoveDependency(DependencyProperty prop)
{
  var registeredPropertyField = typeof(DependencyProperty).
    GetField("RegisteredPropertyList", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
  object list = registeredPropertyField.GetValue(null);
  var genericMeth = list.GetType().GetMethod("Remove");
  try
  {
    genericMeth.Invoke(list, new[] { prop });
  }
  catch (TargetInvocationException)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Does not exist in list");
  }

  var propertyFromNameField = typeof(DependencyProperty).
    GetField("PropertyFromName", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
  var propertyFromName = (Hashtable)propertyFromNameField.GetValue(null);

  object keyToRemove = null;
  foreach (DictionaryEntry item in propertyFromName)
  {
    if (item.Value == prop)
      keyToRemove = item.Key;
  }
  if (keyToRemove != null)
  propertyFromName.Remove(keyToRemove);
}
```

It worked well enough for me to run my tests without getting an "AlreadyRegistered" exception. However, I strongly recommend that you **do not use this in any sort of production code.** There is likely a reason that MSFT chose not to have a formal way to unregister a dependency property, and attempting to go against it is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Very good! You're right that I wouldn't want to use it in production code but a very nice job of detective work!

Answer (score 2):

If everything else fails, you can create a new AppDomain for every Test.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can un-register a dependency property but you can redefine it by overriding the metadata like this:

```
MyDependencyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyNewType), 
                     new PropertyMetadata());
```

Answer (score 0):

If we register name for a Label like this :

```
Label myLabel = new Label();
this.RegisterName(myLabel.Name, myLabel);
```

We can easily unregister the name by using :

```
this.UnregisterName(myLabel.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing scenario where I created a custom control that inherits from `Selector` which is meant to have two ItemsSource properties, `HorizontalItemsSource` and `VerticalItemsSource`.

I don't even use the ItemsControl property, and don't want the user to be able to access it.

So I read [statenjason's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146794/any-way-to-un-register-a-wpf-dependency-property/1412194#1412194), and it gave me a huge POV on how to remove a DP.
However, my problem was, that since I declared the `ItemsSourceProperty` member and the `ItemsSource` as `Private Shadows` (`private new` in C#), I couldn't load it at design time since using `MyControlType.ItemsSourceProperty` would refer to the shadowed variable.
Also, when using the loop mentioned in is enswer above (`foreach DictionaryEntry` etc.), I had an exception thrown saying that the collection has changed during iteration.

Therefore I came up with a slightly different approach where the DependencyProperty is hardcodedly refered at runtime, and the collection is copied to array so it's not changed (VB.NET, sorry):

```
Dim dpType = GetType(DependencyProperty)
Dim bFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Static

Dim FromName = 
  Function(name As String, ownerType As Type) DirectCast(dpType.GetMethod("FromName",
    bFlags).Invoke(Nothing, {name, ownerType}), DependencyProperty)

Dim PropertyFromName = DirectCast(dpType.GetField("PropertyFromName", bFlags).
  GetValue(Nothing), Hashtable)

Dim dp = FromName.Invoke("ItemsSource", GetType(DimensionalGrid))
Dim entries(PropertyFromName.Count - 1) As DictionaryEntry
PropertyFromName.CopyTo(entries, 0)
Dim entry = entries.Single(Function(e) e.Value Is dp)
PropertyFromName.Remove(entry.Key)
```

**Important note:** the above code is all surrounded in the shared constructor of the custom control, and I don't have to check wether it's registered, because I know that a sub-class of Selcetor DOES provide that `ItemsSource` dp.

Answer (score 0):

Had an issue with a ContentPresenter with different Datatemplates where one of them had a DependencyProperty with a PropertyChangedCallback
When changing ContentPresenters content to another DataTemplate the callback remained.

In the UserControls Unloaded event i called:

```
BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(this);
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate { return null; }), null);
```

That worked for me