# Unregistering properties created with DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached

Tags: c#, silverlight, dependency-properties

After creating a `DependencyProperty` with `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached` ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597497%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)), is there any way to *un*-register them from the owner type?

Answer (score 2):

While [there is technically a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146794/any-way-to-un-register-a-wpf-dependency-property/1412194#1412194), it's a particularly nasty piece of code that plays around with the internals of the `DependencyProperty` class. The author even noted that his method should not be used in production code.

With that being said, there is no framework-provided way to unregister a dependency property. *And, as a side note, I'm not sure why you'd want to do such a thing in the first place.*

Comment: That looks rather awful. I'd like to be able to unregister them because I'm trying to use bound dependency properties to [listen to changes in nested properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882393/co-opting-binding-to-listen-to-propertychanged-events-without-a-frameworkelement) on other objects.